# Jquery retrieve form selected option text and print table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, printing

I want to print the form with all the input values and selected option text. It works for the rest of the text and number inputs but the problem is with the select options. Whatever option is selected it only prints the first option from the dropdown (T4 + T4). I want it to print the text from the option that is selected

```
<div id="printContent">
<table border="1" class="css-serial" id="POITable">
                <!-- Rand Titlu -->
                <tr>
                    <th>Nr</th>
                    <th>Latime (mm)</th>
                    <th>Lungime (mm)</th> 
                    <th>Cantitate</th>
                    <th>Material</th>
                    <th>Client</th>
                    <th>Suprafata (m2)</th>
                    <th>Total (€)</th>
                    <th>Sterge</th>
                </tr>
                    <!-- Rand 1 formular -->
                <tr class="item">
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td><input id="latime_sticla" type="number" class="form-control lat amount" value=""></td>
                    <td><input id="lungime_sticla" type="number" class="form-control lung amount" value=""></td>
                    <td><input type="number" class="form-control cant amount" value=""></td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="materialSticla" name="material" class="form-control price amount" onchange="calculPret()">
                            <option value="13.5">T4+T4</option>
                            <option value="14.5">T4+Low</option>
                            <option value="16.1">T4+4 Anotimpuri</option>
                            <option value="18.5">T4+P</option>
                            <option value="20.8">T4+Stopsol</option>
                            <option value="16.5">T4+Niagara Alb</option>
                            <option value="14.7">T4+Delta Alb</option>
                            <option value="15.5">T4+Diamant</option>
                            <option value="15.5">T4+Krizet</option>
                            <option value="16.5">T4+Cincilla Alb</option>
                            <option value="19.5">T4+Niagara Bronz</option>
                            <option value="19.5">T4+Delta Bronz</option>
                            <option value="19.5">T4+Cincilla Bronz</option>
                            <option value="19.8">Oglinda+Oglinda</option>
                            <option value="21.5">Oglinda+Mat Alb</option>
                            <option value="24.5">Oglinda+Mat Bronz</option>
                            <option value="24.21">T4+T4+4 Anotimpuri</option>
                            <option value="25.6">T4+4 Anotimpuri+Low</option>
                            <option value="26.8">T4+T4+Mat Alb</option>
                            <option value="27.8">T4+T4+Mat Bronz</option>
                            <option value="29.6">T4+4 Anotimpuri + Mat Alb</option>
                            <option value="30.6">T4+4 Anotimpuri + Mat Bronz</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value=""></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="suprafata" class="form-control totals" id="totals" value=""readonly="readonly"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="total" class="form-control total" id="total1" value=""readonly="readonly"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="delPOIbutton" value=" - " onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </div>
```

Here is the javascript

```
function calculPret() {

$(".item").each(function () {
            var lat = 1;
            var lung = 1;
            var cant = 1;
            var price = 1;
            var total = 1;
            if (!isNaN(parseFloat($(this).find(".lat").val()))) {
                lat = parseFloat($(this).find(".lat").val());
            }
            if (!isNaN(parseFloat($(this).find(".lung").val()))) {
                lung = parseFloat($(this).find(".lung").val());
            }
            if (!isNaN(parseFloat($(this).find(".cant").val()))) {
                cant = parseFloat($(this).find(".cant").val());
            }
             if (!isNaN(parseFloat($(this).find(".price").val()))) {
                price = parseFloat($(this).find(".price").val());
            }

            var arie = (lung * lat);
            var arieM = (arie / 1000000);
            var pretTotal = (arieM * price * cant);
            total = pretTotal;
            $(this).find(".totals").val(arieM.toFixed(2));
            $(this).find(".total").val(total.toFixed(2));
        });

var sum = 0;

$(".total").each(function () {

    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
        sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }
    });

var sumsuprafata = 0;

$(".totals").each(function () {

    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
        sumsuprafata += parseFloat(this.value);
        }
    });

    $("#totalSuprafata").val(sumsuprafata.toFixed(2));
    $("#totalPret").val(sum.toFixed(2));
    $("#TVA").val(sum.toFixed(2) * 0.19);
    $("#totalPretTVA").val(parseFloat(sum.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(($("#TVA").val())));
}

function printDiv() {

$('form input[type=number]').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('value', $(this).val());
});

$('form input[type=text]').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('value', $(this).val());
});

$("select").change(function() {
    $(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text);
});

  var divToPrint = document.getElementById('printContent');
  newWin = window.open("");
  newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
  newWin.print();
  newWin.close();
}
```

[here is an example, the options were not T4+T4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZQAR.png)

Comment: Add your `calculPret()` code

Comment: I edited the post

Comment: what you want to print n where?

Comment: I want to print the table in the page on my printer, or to save as pdf, like when you hit ctrl+p. Everything works fine but the selection box stay's the same, doesn't matter what option you choose, look at the picture

Comment: You mean you want simple text after selection right?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe that your goal is to make sure that when you write the contents of the table to the new window, that the selected value will be selected in the new window.
So, in other words, you need to make sure that the `'selected'` attribute exists on the `<option>` tag which was selected by the user.

So:

```
$('select').change(function() {
    $(this.options).removeAttr('selected');
    $(this.options[this.selectedIndex]).attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

Explanation:

```
$(this.options).removeAttr('selected');
```

Removes the `selected` attribute from the previous choice, and

```
$(this.options[this.selectedIndex]).attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Adds the `selected` attribute to the new chosen `<option>`.

Hope this helps.